# First array element get removed when added key 0 to other element in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I have a PHP array

```
$arr = array(10,2,3,0=>4,5,6);


echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arr);
```

my Expected result was

```
<pre>array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(4)
  [1]=>
  int(10)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  int(3)
  [4]=>
  int(5)
  [5]=>
  int(6)
}
```

But my result is

```
<pre>array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(4)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(5)
  [4]=>
  int(6)
}
```

From the documentation it says

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

**Example #5 Keys not on all elements**

```
<?php
$array = array(
         "a",
         "b",
    6 => "c",
         "d",
);
var_dump($array);
?>


array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "d"
}
```

**here I can understand that no other element have the key 6 . and in my case i think because the first element also have the key 0 . it get removed .

But because we have added key 0 to another element externally , i feel that 10 should have key 1 . please explain this . thank you very much .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you cite does *not* match your actual use case. In it you are explicitly setting an array key *which is not yet defined*. In your example you are defining an array key *which has already been defined*. Thus in your situation you are overriding the original value with the new value you have set later in your array declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer to your problem is in example 2 on that page.

```
<?php
$array = array(
    1    => "a",
    "1"  => "b",
    1.5  => "c",
    true => "d",
);
var_dump($array);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(1) "d"
}
```

i.e. later entries in an array creation will over-write earlier entries.  Because in the array you created the first element "10" is assigned the key 0, the later entry 0=>4 overwrites it.  Therefore what you are seeing is the expected result from array creation in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is , You are defining the value for a key which is already assigned to a value. Let me explain it a bit.

When the PHP interpreter runs through the array, It assigns

```
[0] -> 10
[1] -> 2
[2] -> 3
```

then it sees `[0] -> 4` ,

So it replace the `[0] -> 10` with `[0] -> 4`
So on..

```
[3] -> 5
[4] -> 6
```

Hope you will understand.